# a member to vs. a member of

Tags: collocations

I sometimes see or hear "a member to" while in a couple of dictionaries that I've checked there's only "a member of". Examples of the former are as follows,

> The SBS is a member to the Health and Human Services (HHS) ...

> EACO is a Member to the Global Alliance for the Rights of Older People.

> 25 original ITA countries are members to the ITA extension...

Are they considered correct usage of the word member? If so, is there a rule regarding when to use "to" and "of"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Member **to**" is never correct. The Oxford Collocations Dictionary and [Ozdic collocations dictionary](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/member) **only** lists "of" as the correct preposition that can be used with "member".

Other prepositions can also be used it depends on the context. "To" can be used with "member" in a sentence like: "He sent all the **members to** the national assembly".